# iOS >> Device Orientation >> Screen is Not Supporting Upside Down

Tags: ios, device-orientation

I have a screen that supports Device Orientation.

Everything is working fine except for the fact that when I rotate the device upside down (home button at top), the rotation doesn't work (it's stuck on the last landscape settings).

I know of several places needed be updated to support this:

- In the VC itself, I added the methods:

[image]

- In the Project Target, I updated as follow:

[image]

- In the Storyboard VC Scene, I updated as follow:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Look ........ http://stackoverflow.com/a/33411646/294884

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You also have to allow rotating to all orientations *in every parent view controller* of the current main view controller. For example, if your view controller is in navigation controller, try subclassing it and override the same methods as in your example.

**Edit:** As [@JordanC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123009/ios-device-orientation-screen-is-not-supporting-upside-down/20124090?noredirect=1#comment61709122_20124090) mentioned, since iOS 7 you can implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` method to return custom supported orientations:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
```

Comment: Yes, I guess this is needed only for Upside Down on iPhone, because that one is not supported by Navigation Controller by default.

Comment: BTW, So if I have several VCs on a navigation stack and I wish to have the first one NOT rotatable (while the ones that follow are) - It seems like once I've subclassed UINavigationController and set it to be rotatable, I cannot set its child VC to not accept rotation. Any thoughts?

Comment: @OhadRegev I don’t think this is really possible. Try overriding `supportedInterfaceOrientations` of your navigation controller to return supported orientations of its `topViewController`. However, this would not prevent popping to the first view controller in illegal orientation. The only solution I see, is to disable „Back“ button when the previous VC doesn’t support current orientation.

Comment: If a UITabBarController is present, note that you will have to subclass and override the - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations {} method of that class as well (in addition to the UINavigationController).

Comment: You no longer need to subclass nav controller. You can set your VC as the delegate and implement `- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UINavigationController *)navigationController`

Answer (score 1):

As @eGanges mentioned the key point could be to subclass your `UITabBarController` (and override `supportedInterfaceOrientations`) if that is your initial view controller, in that case this is the only controller you should subclass (and of course you should add all the supported interface orientations to your app Info.plist file `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` key)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested on real device?

anyway try this:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Comment: `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` as posted will cover these as well.

Comment: Well, I tested it on real device, and it has the same problem. Also, I've tried what you had suggested (using the | operator) and no good here as well...