# Is there any way to lock simulator orientation in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios8, uiinterfaceorientation, xcode6.1, xcode-6.2

For some weird reason the simulator/device won't change the orientation of my app. My code is not deprecated and according to people who are using it on Xcode 6.2, they say it works. However, for my iOS 8 simulators and devices it won't rotate. I'm using ONLY Portrait and UpsideDown orientation. I have everything the way it's supposed to be in info.plist and deployment info.

Is there a button on Xcode 6.1 that I may have accidentally clicked on to lock orientation for simulators/devices?

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);

}
```

//in appdelegate.m  ...

```
CGSize iosScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if (iosScreenSize.height == 667) {

    UIStoryboard *iPhone6 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone6" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *initialViewController =[iPhone6 instantiateInitialViewController];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];

    self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: Hi @jet again ... Maybe this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525657/ios-8-upside-down-orientation-xcode-option-enabled-still-doenst-work

Comment: I found my issue, it's my code in  AppDelegate.m that causes device orientation code not to work. In AppDelegate.m I used code to make iPhone 5 fit inside iPhone 6 and that code stops the Upside Down device orientation. Do you know how to make the device orientation code work with code in AppDelegate.m?

Comment: Maybe you have the same problem that I have with an app. My situation was with UIImagePicker, this object must have Portrait orientation but my app have only Landscape permitted. So, I must detect the exact moment when change to portrait and detect in AppDelegate to change original Landscape (for orientation retriction)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104390/appdelegate-m-code-negatively-affects-device-orientation
I asked a question on stack overflow. The title of the question is above. It describes my issue.

Comment: - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
#pragma unused (application, window)
    if (portraitAllow == YES) {
        portraitAllow = NO;
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
        else  /* iphone */
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
}

Comment: Obviously is just a similar, but maybe the method used in AppDelegate could be help you. Good luck.

Comment: I used the above code that I edited in so I can make my own storyboard for iPhone 6. That above code stops UpSide Down orientation from working. When I remove that code in appdelegate.m the UpSide down orientation works. Don't know how to make it that UpSide Down orientation works along with that code in appdelegate.m

Comment: Check if iosScreenSize.height returns 667 or was exchange by 375 (width).  Sometimes happens in newest Xcode with no auto layout.

Comment: no, that had nothing to do with it, nothing changed.

Comment: I understand you better than you think. At the end, i will fix with workarounds and make Storyboards (each one by device), and then, I start with Auto Layout. Sorry, but I believe you walk by this path, but maybe you have a better luck than me (and I hope :) ). For this situation i don't have more ideas.

Comment: Well thanks for all your help, i hope I figure it out too.