# Can't figure out how to get UpSide down orientation to work in iOS 8?

Tags: ios8, uiinterfaceorientation, appdelegate, device-orientation, uiscreen

I added UIScreen bounds code in AppDelegate.m for iPhone 6 and now device orientation for iPhone 6 won't work for Portrait/ Upside Down. Upside Down is what's not working in simulator and devices.

Code in AppDelegate.m

```
 CGSize iosScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (iosScreenSize.height == 667) {

        UIStoryboard *iPhone6 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone6" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *initialViewController =[iPhone6 instantiateInitialViewController];

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];

        self.window.rootViewController = initialViewController;

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
```

When I included the above code the simulator and device for iPhone 6 doesn't detect Upside Down orientation. I also used nativeBounds and screenBounds, didn't work either for Upside Down orientation.

My code for device orientation...

```
 -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
 }
```

I have no idea what to do to get AppDelegate code to let UpSide Down orientation be detected for iPhone 6.

Comment: LOOK: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33411646/294884

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally figured this one out.

Then realized someone posted the answer here: [Setting device orientation in Swift iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651969/setting-device-orientation-in-swift-ios/25653474#comment52194689_25653474)

Go down to DaRk-_-D0G's answer.

I had to subclass my tab bar controller *just* to override that method. Very obnoxious .