# iPhone's Portrait height - 'Regular', Upside Down one - 'Compact' - why?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, rotation, size-classes

I'm studying Size Classes now and I've found out that iPhone 6s in 'Upside Down' device rotation has 'Compact' height while in 'Portrait' it has 'Regular'. It`s interesting because I think it should be the same. I marked 'Upside Down' in the Deployment Info.

You could try my test app where you can choose a device and see which dimensions it actually has. Green arrow means 'Regular', red- 'Compact', and no arrows - 'Any'.

https://github.com/VictorShurapov/ShowSizeClass

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have found the solution there [iOS 8 upside down orientation, XCode option enabled, still doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525657/ios-8-upside-down-orientation-xcode-option-enabled-still-doesnt-work). Now I know that this Device Orientations' options in the Deployment Info are only the supporting ones. And if you actually want to use 'Upside Down' you need to do this override for particular ViewController:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
{
  return .All
}
```